# Why is addBirth method returns null?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have this method but in run-time it will be thrown nullpointerexception,why?

my method:

```
public static boolean isAddBirth(String name, String family, String fatherName, String mName, String dOfBirth, String pOfBirth) {
    ResultSet rst;
    boolean bool = false;
    Statement stmt;
    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();



        rst = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM birthtable");


        while (rst.next()) {
            if (rst.getString(2).equals(name) && rst.getString(3).equals(family) && rst.getString(4).equals(fatherName) && rst.getString(5).equals(mName) && rst.getString(6).equals(dOfBirth) && rst.getString(7).equals(pOfBirth)) {
                bool = false;
            } else {
                bool = true;
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Manager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return bool;




}
```

stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at database.Manager.isAddBirth(Manager.java:164)
    at AdminGUI.AddNewBornInformation.submit(AddNewBornInformation.java:356)
    at AdminGUI.AddNewBornInformation.setButtonActionPerformed(AddNewBornInformation.java:283)
    at AdminGUI.AddNewBornInformation.access$800(AddNewBornInformation.java:28)
    at AdminGUI.AddNewBornInformation$9.actionPerformed(AddNewBornInformation.java:140)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6038)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3265)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5803)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2058)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4410)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2116)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4322)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:3986)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:3916)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2102)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2429)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:273)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:183)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:173)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:168)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:160)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:121)
```

ALSO these are in my class:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
private static Connection conn = DBManager.getConnection();
```

Comment: The stack trace indicates that it's occuring at line 164. Which line in the method is 164? This will help us pinpoint the problem.

Comment: 164 is : if (rst.getString(2).equals(name) && rst.getString(3).equals(family) && rst.getString(4).equals(fatherName) && rst.getString(5).equals(mName) && rst.getString(6).equals(dOfBirth) && rst.getString(7).equals(pOfBirth)){}

Comment: Also your code could be easier to decypher with some clearer names. I see that you're trying to see if there's a record in the table with the parameters you're passing. You could do this a different way by simply adding a `where` clause to your SQL statement. I think this might be more efficient than fetching the entire table and iterating in Java. This way you can just see if the result set is empty or not.

Comment: I guess rst is not null since you're able to call `.next()` on it. Do you know that you have the expected number of fields avaiable? i.e. one of your `getString` calls might be returning `null`

Comment: Every night you post a "NullPointerExcpetion" question. When will you ever learn to figure it out on your own. Why is this so hard??? The stack trace tells you the line causing the problem!!!

Comment: Note to people anwering these postings. YOU ARE NOT doing the poster a favour by spoon feeding the answers. This is a HOMEWORK question. This is cheating! All you have to do is look at the other postings made by Johanna and you will see what I mean.

Comment: @camickr, As a teacher I don't think this is cheating... there is code posted so work is being done (hopefully by the poster).  Now if the poster does keep asking this sort of thing, then yeah, they should really learn how to read a stack trace.  However providing code that is better written so that the error can more easily be figured out is not a bad thing - especially if the poster learns that doing it a different way makes their life easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you didn't provide line number 164 I'll take a guess that it is:

```
if (rst.getString(2).equals(name) && rst.getString(3).equals(family) && rst.getString(4).equals(fatherName) && rst.getString(5).equals(mName) && rst.getString(6).equals(dOfBirth) && rst.getString(7).equals(pOfBirth))
```

First off that line makes me want to cry.

Let's fix it:

```
String a;
String b;
String c;
String d;
String e;
String f;

a = rst.getString(2);
b = rst.getString(3);
c = rst.getString(4);
d = rst.getString(5);
e = rst.getString(6);
f = rst.getString(7);

if (!(a.equals(name))
{
    bool = false;
}

if(!(b.equals(family))
{
    bool = false;
}

if(!(c.equals(fatherName))
{
    bool = false;
}

if(!(d.equals(mName))
{
    bool = false;
}

if(!(e.equals(dOfBirth))
{
    bool = false;
}

if(!(f.equals(pOfBirth))
{
    bool = false;
}
```

That will at least show you the line that has the null pointer on it (assuming my guess is correct).

Also, a-e are terrible names... you should pick better ones than I did.

The real solution here is to use Object Oriented programming as it is intended... let's make a Person class:

```
public class Person
{
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
    private final String middleName; // guessing that is what mName is...
    private final String fathersName;
    private final String dateOfBirth;
    private final String placeOfBirth; // guessing that is what pOfBirth is...

    public Person(final String firstName,
                  final String lastName,
                  final String middleName,
                  final String fathersName,
                  final String dateOfBirth,
                  final String placeOfBirth)
    {
        if(firstName == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("firstName cannot be null");
        }

        if(lastName == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("lastName cannot be null");
        }

        ... etc for all of the other arguments ...

        // I would never do the this.fristName thing.. .I would name the parameter different than the instance vairable...
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName  = lastName;

        ... etc for all of the other arguments ... 
    }

    public boolean equals(final Object o)
    {
        final Person person;

        if(!(o instanceof Person))
        {
            return (false);
        }

        other = (Person)o;

        // the code you I put above + your code for checking if they are equal
    }

    public int hashCode()
    {
        // this is probably good enough
        return (firstName.hashCode() + lastName.hashCode());
    }
}
```

Then in your method you would have code something like:

```
rst = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM birthtable");

    while (rst.next()) 
    {
        final Person person;

        // I would use temp variables rather than passing in the result of getString directly...
        person = new Person(rst.getString(2),
                            rst.getString(3),
                            rst.getString(4),
                            rst.getString(5),
                            rst.getString(6),
                            rst.getString(7));

        // otherPerson would be passed into the method instead of the String you are passing now
        bool = person.equals(otherPerson);

        ... etc ...
    }
```

Comment: You know, you could pretty much halve the size of that code by initializing the variables on the same line they are declared and moving the opening braces to the end of the line rather than putting them on the line below.

Comment: And removing the braces entirely and removing the extra set of brackets in each "if"...

Comment: it return NP exception again for the first if,:(((

Comment: I wouldn't write the code like that to begin with (editing my answer).  I do always use the { and } on their own lines... I try to keep my methods small - about 10 lines of code per method... and about 20 lines of horizontal space.  Making it take more space shows me whan I have done way too much in a method.

Comment: if you are getting a null pointer on the first line then it is because the rst.getString is empty... presumably because it selected no data.  Try adding a System.out.println(rst) to see (JDBC isn't really my thing so debugging advice specific to that is limited :-)

Comment: @Anon I never (save one case - ints used in a switch, and then only because the compiler forces it) init a variable where it is declared.  I value consistency above pretty much everything, and since some variables cannot be initialized where declared none should be.  Also if you do that and the brace moving etc... you falsely make the method look smaller than it is... and I like (very) small methods.

Comment: I would argue that excessive boilerplate should be avoided. By adding lines consisting solely of braces, you're making the method look exceptionally large and complex when really it isn't. Similarly for declaring local variables and then immediately initializing them on a separate line. Useless boilerplate like that means you fit less useful information on the screen at a time, which generally decreases productivity.

Comment: Actually I would say that method is large and complex and deserves to stand out.  Something with 7 variables is complex.  Like I said my code tends to be about 10 executable lines and a total length of about 20 screen lines including whitespace lines and { } pairs.  An example is at https://chaos.bcit.ca/svn/public/astar/ I should probably refactor the double for loops in the Maze class too to make them smaller.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, even if it were working, that code wouldn't do what you wanted it to. Not even close.

Second, it would help if we knew what line the exception was on. In lieu of that, though, we can narrow it down to one of the following:

1. `conn` is null.
2. `conn.createStatement();` returns null.
3. `stmt.executeQuery()` returns null.
4. One of the `rst.getString()`s returns null.

I'm sure you can figure it out from there.

Comment: About 3. As per API documentation this method call should never return null.http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery(java.lang.String).

Answer (score 1):

I think the likely cause is that the "getString" method is returning null.
The API documentation of this method indicates that it can return null.

String getString(int columnIndex)
[...]

Returns:
the column value; if the value is SQL NULL, the value returned is **null**

The above API doc reference is from:
[ResultSet](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)

Answer (score 0):

For your program to be less prone to NullPointerExceptions, you could *assume* that the your input variables are not null (or *ensure* that in the beginning of your method), and the invert the comparation:

```
if (name.equals(rst.getString(1)) && ...
```

The other alternative, which I don't have any problems with, is to use the method ObjectUtils.equals(obj1, obj2) from the commons-lang library, it will return true only if both objects are null or if obj1.equals(obj2), every other possibility will return false. The classes ObjectUtils and StringUtils have a lot of methods that are null-safe, it's worth taking a look.